# jest toMatchSnapshot removes inline styles

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a consistent repro with the following jest test:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ background: 'linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue)'}}>Loooo</div>
  )
}
```

Then trying to take a snapshot in a unit test produces:

```
test('match snapshot', () => {
  const {container}= render(<App />);
  expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Produces this snapshot:

```
exports[`match snapshot 1`] = `
<div>
  <div>
    Loooo
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

**But!!!**

If we change `linear-gradient` to something else like this:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ background: 'red'}}>Loooo</div>
  )
}
```

We get what we expect:

```
exports[`match snapshot 1`] = `
<div>
  <div
    style="background: red;"
  >
    Loooo
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

Does anyone one know what kind of treachery is this? Why linear-gradient is being cut out?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently cssstyle does not parse the linear-gradient and returns undefined.

Filed an [issue](https://github.com/jsdom/cssstyle/issues/148)